# insert multiple values with one parameter with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would need your help. I have a project that I need to insert multiple records into my table. Here is more detail. I design a purchase order table with 3 columns (a, b, c):

- a: is primary key with identity (1,1) primary key
- b: date
- c: is varchar(50)

I want to have multiple records with same value of a. For ex: when I create purchase order # 1. I have multiple records inside the PO# 1. Also with PO# 2, I have multiple records....also so on.

How can I write a stored procedure for this needed?

Comment: Could you provide us the structure of "my table"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to be able to pass in N records' worth of information into the stored procedure in one call?  If so, I would passing in a blob of XML and parse it inside the stored proc.  Then write each record in a loop.